# Can I use video and HDMI output at the same time?

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, video

I've got my Raspberry Pi to work as a torrentbox and mediacenter AIO. Can I hook up the HDMI to my beamer and the RCA output to my TV?

I guessing I cannot since it's an analog signal and a digital signal and the Raspberry Pi has to switch. But it'd be nice if I could get confirmation of that.

Or is there a way I can split the HDMI to an analog signal (my TV is very oldschool)?

PS: Just to make sure I'm trying to display the same screen on both my TV and my beamer.

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't work, by default if HDMI is connected, Pi is forced to display output through HDMI port only. To display via RCA, you need to unplug the HDMI.

Since you need to display through both simultaneously, it's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

I never tried to use both outputs at the same time (my TV isn't that old) but it seems that it is not possible.

A cursory search showed that both HDMI splitters and HDMI to RCA converters are commercially available, but I haven't seen a combination of both. However, this was just a very quick search and maybe you're more successful if you dig a bit deeper.